# CSS styles won't update before fetching file

Tags: javascript, css, asynchronous, async-await

**Intended Goal** - User selects different colors from various color inputs and creates their own theme. Once the colors are chosen, the user clicks the download button and gets the generated CSS file with the colors he/she chose.

**Issue** - I'm able to download the CSS file, but I'm getting the original values despite changing the inputs to different colors.

**What I've Done**

The CSS file that's being downloaded already exists and all of the colors that correspond to different elements are done via CSS variables.

I'm updating the changes live by doing the following.

```
import { colors } from './colorHelper'

const inputs = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('input[type="color"]'));

const handleThemeUpdate = (colors) => {
  const root = document.querySelector(':root');
  const keys = Object.keys(colors);
  keys.forEach(key => {
    root.style.setProperty(key, colors[key]);
  });
}

inputs.forEach((input) => {
  input.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const cssPropName = `--${e.target.id}`;
    document.styleSheets[2].cssRules[3].style.setProperty(cssPropName, e.target.value);

    handleThemeUpdate({
      [cssPropName]: e.target.value
    });
    console.log(`${cssPropName} is now ${e.target.value}`)
  });
});
```

Then, I fetched the stylesheet from the server, grabbed all the CSS Variables and replaced them with their actual value (hex color value).

After that, I got the return value (new stylesheet without variables) and set it for the data URI.

```
async function updatedStylesheet() {
  const res = await fetch("./prism.css");
  const orig_css = await res.text();
  let updated_css = orig_css;

  const regexp = /(?:var\(--)[a-zA-z\-]*(?:\))/g;
  let cssVars = orig_css.matchAll(regexp);
  cssVars = Array.from(cssVars).flat();

  for (const v of cssVars) {
     updated_css = updated_css.replace(v,   colors[v.slice(6, -1)]);
   };

  return updated_css;
}

const newStylesheet = updatedStylesheet().then(css => {
 downloadBtn.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(css));
 downloadBtn.setAttribute('download', 'prism-theme.css');
})
```

I already have a download button setup in my HTML and I grabbed it earlier in my script so that it was available anywhere for me to use. `downloadBtn`

I set up the button to fire and grabbed the  new sheet.

```
downloadBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  newStylesheet();
});
```

**The Result**

I get the initial color values of the stylesheet despite changing the colors within the color inputs on the page. So the CSS file isn't being updated with the new colors before I download the file.

Answer (score 0):

You could use PHP to pass the values to a new page. Let's say you chose the colors you want then click a button that says "Generate" that takes you to the "Generate Page".

The values would be passed directly into the HTML and you would download from the Generate Page instead.

This is if you know PHP of course, just a suggestion on how you might solve it.

(would comment, but can't due to reputation)

Comment: I appreciate the response, but I know nothing of PHP and would like a JavaScript only answer.